# Dynamically setting call,sms, email functionality in sencha touch

Tags: html, sencha-touch, extjs, sencha-touch-2

I have an application where i have implemented call,sms,email functionality as shown below, i wanted to know how do i make the phone number:99999999 and mailto:example@gmail.com dynamic , so that i will replace the phone number and email field from some variable.

SMS functionality
{

```
                        xtype: 'button',
                        flex: 1,
                        ui: 'action',
                        text: 'SMS',
                        id: 'smsButton',
                        handler: function () {
                            window.location = 'sms:**99999999**';
                        }

                    }
```

Call Functionality

```
{
                             xtype: 'img',
                             text: 'Phone',
                             src: 'http://src.sencha.io/x30/x30/https://support.skype.com/assets/20120601134928/images/categories64/call.png',
                             id: 'callMeButton',
                             flex: 3,
                             tap: function () {
                                 window.location = 'tel:**999999999**';

                             }

                         }
```

Email Functionality:

```
{
                         xtype: 'button',
                         text: 'Email',
                         ui: 'action',
                         flex: 1,
                         id: 'emailButton',
                         handler: function () {
                                 `window.location = 'mailto:`**example@gmail.com**';


}
                     }
```

Comment: Store them in global variables and populate them with their corresponding values when you call a function related to the functionality.

Comment: I have phone number and email values in the variable, i am confused how do i set it inside the window.location syntax

Comment: window.location = 'mailto'+yourvariable;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store your values of sms number, email address and call number in some address like shown below ..

```
var contactNo = "**9999999**";  
var emailId = "example@gmail.com";  
var smsNo = "**99999999**";
```

and then make call as shown below,

```
 window.location.href = "sms:"+smsNo;
 window.location.href = "mailto:"+emailId;
 window.location.href = "tel:"+contactNo;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by just using the `<a>` tag

For phone number

```
<a href="tel:999999999">999999999</a>
```

For E-Mail

```
<a href="mailto:webmaster@example.com">webmaster@example.com</a>
```

For SMS

```
<a href="sms:999999999">Send SMS</a>
```

Tapping on the link will automatically summon the corresponding app in both android and iOS.